# Android BLE receiver/transmitter stack - across multiple activities

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been researching using BLE within an Android app, but still cannot work out if it's possible to create a common receiver/transmit BLE stack. My application will have multiple activities and the information displayed will be based on the BLE receiver data, but I will also transmit data to the device to turn GPIO pins.

The examples of implementing BLE are based on a single activity and not a common stack. Ideally, I want my application from the start it will search for a BLE device with a pre-defined device ID and start to receive the data.

As the user moves around the different activities, the BLE stack keeps receiving data rather than having to repeat the BLE code in each activity.

Could anyone give me some advice if this is possible and where would the BLE stack be placed within the project code structure?

Comment: Create [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) for handling the BLE communication. And the term *BLE stack* is confusing in this context and probably incorrect for what you are building.

Comment: Would it be better to ask for the BLE communications code to be a background task while the user is looking at the different activities?

Comment: A service is straight-forward to access from several activities. Another option is to use a class with a singleton instance for easy access and a background task as a major part of the implementation.